# .bat file - cd to a directory with a space in its name and also using a variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file

ive written a quick .bat file that reads in the name of a directory typed in by the user, i store that variable in a variable, and then i want to actually cd to that directory.

i've tested it out with simple directories like "C:," for instance, and that works. however, when i'm dealing with the user entering in something like "C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop," i can't do cd %directory%\sampleFolder.

i keep getting an error of "the system cannot find the path specified," even though i'm using the full name. anyone know how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set /p DIR="path:"
cd %DIR%
```

Works just fine.

Comment: strange, still no go for me. but i'll try again later, thanks (and to everyone else) for helping :)

Comment: @splatback: Maybe you're using a version of Microsoft Windows that's too old (older version of cmd.exe? or maybe command.com?) or too new (Microsoft Windows Vista, Microsoft Windows 7), which do not have that directory...

Comment: @Johannes : It won't do that. Changing %PATH% from a terminal only changes it for that terminal. The system PATH stays the same... but yes...

Comment: That's obvious. It still prevents you from running most applications from that console until you either re-set PATH or close it.

Comment: This is not working in a batch file. Actually even with `cd "%DIR%"`, I can not make it work.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
cd "%directory%\sampleFolder"
```

Comment: yeah, thats the weird thing, i thought it should work too, but for some reason it's not...

Comment: do you think you could send me the code on how you did it? please :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Enter Directory
SET/p directory=
CHDIR %directory%
```

Works for me (Windows 7) but should work for XP/Vista/etc